# TypeError: DatetimeIndex(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '2020-06-21 12:14:33' was passed

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I building API for ML model using flask When I enter data and then prediction, I get the following error:
TypeError: DatetimeIndex(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '2020-06-21
12:14:33' was passed

```
    trans_date_trans_time = request.form['trans_date_trans_time']
    trans_date = pd.DatetimeIndex(trans_date_trans_time).date
    trans_time = pd.DatetimeIndex(trans_date_trans_time).time
    trans_date = pd.to_datetime(trans_date)
    del trans_date_trans_time

    trans_date = pd.to_datetime(trans_date)
    trans_date = trans_date.map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
    trans_time = pd.to_datetime(trans_time, format='%H:%M:%S')
    trans_time = 3600 * pd.DatetimeIndex(trans_time).hour + 60 * pd.DatetimeIndex(
        trans_time).minute + pd.DatetimeIndex(trans_time)

    merchant = request.form['merchant']
    merchant = label_encoder.fit_transform(merchant)
    category = request.form['category']
    category = label_encoder.fit_transform(category)
    amount = request.form['amount']
    gender = request.form['gender']
    if gender == ['M']:
        gender = 1
    elif gender == ['F']:
        gender = 0
    city = request.form['city']
    city = label_encoder.fit_transform(city)
    state = request.form['state']
    state = label_encoder.fit_transform(state)
    zip = request.form['zip']
    lat = request.form['lat']
    long = request.form['long']
    city_pop = request.form['city_pop']
    job = request.form['job']
    dob = request.form['dob']
    dob = pd.to_datetime(dob)
    age = (pd.to_datetime('now') - dob) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
    age = age.astype(int)
    del dob

    unix_time = request.form['unix_time']
    merch_lat = request.form['merch_lat']
    merch_long = request.form['merch_long']

    d = (
        trans_date, trans_time, merchant, category, amount, gender, city, state, zip, lat, long, city_pop, job, age,
        unix_time, merch_lat, merch_long)

    d = pd.DataFrame(d)
    d = pd.DataFrame.transpose(d)

    prediction = model.predict(d)
    print('the prediction is', prediction)
    # result = prediction.argmax()
    if prediction == 1:
        result = 'it is fraud process '
    elif prediction == 0:
        result = 'it is safe process'
    else:
        result = 'Please enter input values'
    print('the result is', result)
    return render_template('bank.html', result=result)

else:
    return render_template('bank.html')
```

I also did these steps while training the model to process data
I hope to get help

then When I add brackets for argument, another error appears :
TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

```
    trans_date_trans_time = request.form['trans_date_trans_time']
    trans_date = pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_date_trans_time]).date
    trans_time = pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_date_trans_time]).time
    trans_date = pd.to_datetime([trans_date])
    del trans_date_trans_time

    trans_date = pd.to_datetime([trans_date])
    trans_date = trans_date.map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
    trans_time = pd.to_datetime([trans_time], format='%H:%M:%S')
    trans_time = 3600 * pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_time]).hour + 60 * 
        pd.DatetimeIndex(
        [trans_time]).minute + pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_time])

    merchant = request.form['merchant']
    merchant = label_encoder.fit_transform([merchant])
    category = request.form['category']
    category = label_encoder.fit_transform([category])
    amount = request.form['amount']
    gender = request.form['gender']
    if gender == ['M']:
        gender = 1
    elif gender == ['F']:
        gender = 0
    city = request.form['city']
    city = label_encoder.fit_transform([city])
    state = request.form['state']
    state = label_encoder.fit_transform([state])
    zip = request.form['zip']
    lat = request.form['lat']
    long = request.form['long']
    city_pop = request.form['city_pop']
    job = request.form['job']
    dob = request.form['dob']
    dob = pd.to_datetime(dob)
    age = (pd.to_datetime('now') - dob) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
    age = age.astype(int)
    del dob

    unix_time = request.form['unix_time']
    merch_lat = request.form['merch_lat']
    merch_long = request.form['merch_long']

    d = (
        trans_date, trans_time, merchant, category, amount, gender, city, state, zip, lat, long, city_pop, job, age,
        unix_time, merch_lat, merch_long)

    d = pd.DataFrame(d)
    d = pd.DataFrame.transpose(d)

    prediction = model.predict(d)
    print('the prediction is', prediction)
    # result = prediction.argmax()
    if prediction == 1:
        result = 'it is fraud process '
    elif prediction == 0:
        result = 'it is safe process'
    else:
        result = 'Please enter input values'
    print('the result is', result)
    return render_template('bank.html', result=result)

else:
    return render_template('bank.html')
```

Comment: Do you know what line gives the error?

Comment: I think these lines :                                                                                                                  trans_date = pd.DatetimeIndex(trans_date_trans_time).date                                                      trans_time = pd.DatetimeIndex(trans_date_trans_time).time                                                                trans_date = pd.to_datetime(trans_date)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to [wrap the respective arguments in brackets](https://www.edureka.co/community/42334/typeerror-index-called-with-collection-some-kind-email-passed).

So that you have something like

```
trans_date = pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_date_trans_time]).date
# ...
trans_date = pd.to_datetime([trans_date])
```

As far as I understand, the error says that you should give the arguments within a list.

Comment: I did that and another error appeared : arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series                                                                                                                                     the new error appeared on the line :trans_date = pd.to_datetime([trans_date])

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include a detailed traceback of the error?